# PHP file upload to Google Drive

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to upload a file to Google Drive using API. Uploading process works fine but the problem is the uploaded file on the drive is empty(has nothing to show). Why?

Here is the uploading PHP code.

```
  DEFINE("TESTFILE", $_FILES['myFile']);
  DEFINE('TYPE', $_FILES["myFile"]["type"]);

  $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
  $file->setName('HelloWorld');
  $file->setDescription('A test document');

  $result = $service->files->create(
      $file,
      array(
        'data' => TESTFILE,
        'mimeType' => TYPE,
        'uploadType' => 'media'
      )
  );
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

And this is the HTML form:

```
<div>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
<input type="file" name= "myFile">
<input type ="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You are forgetting to upload the file contents you have only uploaded the file metadata describing the file.  There is are extensive examples here https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads on the different types of file upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an intermediary step in your code.

You need to save the uploaded file to disk locally first ( as a temporary file ) and then read that file back into either a variable or file handle which you would then pass in place of `TESTFILE` in your `$service->files->create()` call.

Something like this ...

```
$file_tmp  = $_FILES["myFile"]["tmp_name"];
$file_type = $_FILES["myFile"]["type"];
$file_name = basename($_FILES["myFile"]["name"];

move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "path/to/upload/".$file_name);

$file_data = file_get_contents("path/to/upload/".$file_name);

$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$file->setName('HelloWorld');
$file->setDescription('A test document');

$result = $service->files->create(
  $file,
  array(
    'data' => $file_data,
    'mimeType' => $file_type,
    'uploadType' => 'media'
  )
);
```

But please remember to validate your file uploads for proper type, size, etc. as best practice.

Comment: `$_FILES["myFile"]["type"];` is something to be avoided. Its spoofable. better to use [`mime_content_type()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php). Also, PHP is perfectly capable of reading file contents from the tmp directory without having to move it.

Comment: Xorifelse is correct, reading file contents from 'tmp' worked without moving it. changed made: 'data' => file_get_contents($file_tmp);